# RaisePropertyChanged throwing a StackOverflow Exception on TwoWay Bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I've got the following ComboBox with the SelectedValue bound to the Property below. With the following binding, when I set value, the binding/RaisePropertyChanged combination is throwing a StackOverflow Exception.

Here's the ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WireType" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.WireTypes}" SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.WireType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here's the Property

```
public string WireType
{
    get
    {
        return _wireType;
    }
    set
    {
        _wireType = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And here's the RaisePropertyChanged method.

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've done this before. What am I missing?

Comment: (some of) the stack trace might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that the `PropertyChanged` event is trying to set the property value.

The setter should protect against the case where the value didn't change.  ie-

```
set
{
    if (_wireType != value) // or the appropriate comparison for your specific case
    {
        _wireType = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Of course a stack trace would confirm what's actually happening.

Comment: Well that was a duh moment for me :) Thanks for the quick reply. Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
{
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
}
```

Comment: Mohit. Sorry I missed posting the event. I do already have that in code.